# how to solve ORACLE AUDSYS.SYS space error

Tags: php, oracle

I am having this problem `"Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-02002: error while writing to audit trail ORA-55917: Table flush I/O failed for log ID: 1 bucket ID: 0 ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment AUDSYS.SYS_LOB0000081269C00014$$ by 128 in tablespace SYSAUX ORA-02002: error while writing to audit trail ORA-55917: Table flush I/O failed for log ID: 1 bucket ID: 0 ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment AUDSYS.SYS_LOB0000081269C00014$$ by 128 in tablespace SYSAUX , SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in..."` is there any known solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment AUDSYS.SYS_LOB0000081269C00014$$ by 128 in tablespace SYSAUX

The SYSAUX tablespace is full.

Because the Audit system can't record what you're up to, it won't let you do *anything*.

Most immediately, you need [to get your DBA's] to extend the SYSAUX tablespace so that the Audit system has somewhere to write to.

Then [they need to] dig through the Documentation about how to [move the Audit Trail data](https://wadhahdaouehi.tn/2017/10/move-audit-trail-table-to-created-user-tablespace-with-oracle-database-11g-12c/) *out* of the SYSAUX tablespace and into somewhere [slightly] more manageable.

Then [they need to] dig even deeper to figure out how to [get rid of the Audit trail data](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_admin.htm#GUID-7D2E55CE-2820-47E3-A989-5F7AAB19CD76) that you no longer want (which is probably the vast majority of it!).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably audit events that have filled up your SYSAUX tablespace. As detailed [here](https://smarttechways.com/2018/07/23/sysaux-tablespace-full-with-audsys-objects-in-oracle-database/) can use this procedure to clear out the audit trail. It might take a while to finish:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL(
AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP => FALSE,
CONTAINER => dbms_audit_mgmt.container_current);
END;
/
```

For example:

```
SQL> BEGIN
DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL(
AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP => FALSE,
CONTAINER => dbms_audit_mgmt.container_current);
END;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> select TABLESPACE_NAME,round(USED_PERCENT,2),TABLESPACE_SIZE from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics;

TABLESPACE_NAME            ROUND(USED_PERCENT,2) TABLESPACE_SIZE
------------------------------ --------------------- ---------------
SYSAUX                      5.74         4194302
SYSTEM                      2.53         4194302
```